# PHP application architecture design help

Tags: php, web-applications

I am working on a new social network type app in PHP.  I am wanting to do it all in OO and I do not want to use an existing framework.

I have been studying many different frameworks and libraries to see how they do things like MVC.

So far what I have is something like this...

```
// All request are routed through index.php
// index.php

Get requested page from URI (ie; test.com/user/friends/page-12 )
$controller = User();
$controller_method = friends();
$page = 12; // for paging results
$id = ''; //id is empty in this example but some pages will have an ID number as well
```

So in theory I would load a User class and friends() method.  This all sounds simple and great on a basic site but what I am building will be more complex so I am not sure exactly what  I should do next.  For example on some pages, I will require that a user is authorized already.

So instead of loading a User class and friends method, should I be including a user friends file instead where I can have more stuff happening?  In this case it would load a user file and that file could call user class methods as well as set up paging and do authentication and other things that should be on that page.

Another idea, since this example is calling the user class, what is the user class has methods friends() , profile(), settings() and these methods when called basicly just route to include another file with that will have the main content for that page?
Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: Basically you will have to list out all the functions that you want to provide in your application, and then decide upon controllers and functions. When you do use case diagrams, you can understand easily, for example one use case diagram = one controller as such.

Comment: Why do people always want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I agree with Ikke. Is there any reason in particular that you do not want to use an existing framework?

Comment: @s992 yeah, I learn better buy building my own plus after 2 years of and trying about 12 different frameworks, I havent found one I REALLY like yet

Comment: Fair enough, there's nothing wrong with learning by doing. The best advice I can give you is this: Before you write any more code, sit down with a pencil and paper(or keyboard and Notepad) and map out all the functionality you need and how it all relates. From there, you'll have a much better shot at properly architecting(is this even a word?) your application. Wish I could help more, but I am a huge CodeIgniter fanboy :)

Comment: @Ikke: because the wheel isn't perfect for all (or even most, depending on how you look at it) use-cases.  Sure, a given framework **may** be more appropriate here, but that doesn't mean it is, and that also doesn't mean that it's wrong to investigate other options...  There are lots of reasons not to use an existing framework.  So instead of saying *just use an existing framework*, you might want to try to figure out if the poster looked into that and ruled it out based upon the requirements of the task at hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're learning by doing, you'll likely have to start with designing an overarching ACL (access control list) authentication scheme that gets included by your index.php file by default for every page. Then all controllers (like your `User()` class) need to make use of the ACL (say, by assuming there's a global `$auth` variable, that's a member of your `Auth()` class, or error out).

Here's some structure code to get you started:

Auth.php:

```
class Auth() {
  function login($user, $pass) {
    // Log in a user
  }
  function logout($user) {
    // Log the user out
  }
  function isLoggedIn($user) {
    // Verify that the user is logged in
  }
  function isVerified($user, $action) {
    // Is $user allowed to do $action?
  }
}
```

Index.php:

```
require_once('Auth.php');
$auth = new Auth();
$controller = User();
// ....
```

User.php:

```
class User() {
  function __construct() {
    // Determine if Auth is set up
    global $auth;
    if (!isset($auth) || !is_a($auth, 'Auth')) {
      return false; // Not properly set up for authentication
    }
  }
  function someSecretFunction($user, $password) {
    global $auth; // We know this exists; we checked it when creating the object
    if (!isset($auth) || !is_a($auth, 'Auth')) {
      return false; // Verify that it hasn't changed into something else since we checked
    }
    if ($auth->isVerified($user, 'someSecretFunction')) { // Use ACL functions now that we know we have them
      // ...
    }

  }
}
```